# Passing variable value from one controller to another controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am new in laravel.
I have two controllers with functions 1> CartController@finalizeCart and 2> PaymentController@postPayment. Now, I want to pass the **variable** ***TotalPrice*** from <1> to <2>. My question is: how can I pass value from one controller to another one directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in the first controller

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
```

Then in the second

```
Session::get('key');
```

More info can be found in the documentation here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#session-usage

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to pass data from one controller to another that is passing data by ***cookies***

- Your first controller:

  ```
  $response = Response::make('Hello World');

  return  $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('name', 'value', $minutes));
  ```
- And get it in the next request

  ```
  $value = Cookie::get('name');
  ```